# elasticsearch kibana setup in separate aws ec2 servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed elasticsearch in one instance and kibana in another instance.
Both the services are running and I can connect elasticsearch using curl and its instance public ip with port 9200
version: 7.9.2 both
Assume: Public ips
elasticsearch - x.x.x.x
kibana - y.y.y.y

**Issue:**
Cant connect kibana instance with its curl and public ip with port 5601
Error: Failed to connect to y.y.y.y port 5601: connection refused

**Query:**
Correct config for elasticsearch.yml and kibana.yml

` **kibana.yml:**
port: 5601
server.host: "y.y.y.y"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://x.x.x.x:9200"]

**elasticsearch.yml:**
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200 `

Answer (score 0):

1. It is extremely likely you have not configured the correct security group rules on the kibana instance to permit you to access the service.  You need an ingress rule permitting tcp to port 5601 from whatever your ingress range is.
2. Likewise, it is extremely likely you have not granted access to elasticsearch (x.x.x.x:9200) from y.y.y.y

Check your security group rules.

Also, please ensure your elasticsearch public ip does not permit access from 0.0.0.0 - publically accessible elasticsearch clusters are a prime target for naughty people.

Comment: Yes I have given access for these ports in my security group